# Load an element in the same div using useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to create a simple login page in react. I have used two input fields, one for the username and one for the password. I have a div in which I am rendering an animation using useEffect hook. I want the animation to change in the same div when I either click on the username or password input field, and then get back to the default animation when I click anywhere else on the page.

This is the code which I have written

```
import './App.css';
import { useState,useEffect } from 'react';
import lottie from 'lottie-web';
import sideNod from './sidenod.json';
import nod from './nod.json'

function App() {
  const[userId,setUserId] = useState('');
  const[password,setPassword] = useState('');
  const[touched,setTouched] = useState(false);
  console.log(touched)
  useEffect(() => {
      lottie.loadAnimation({
        container: document.getElementById('avatar'),
        animationData: touched ? nod : sideNod,
        renderer: 'svg',
        loop: true,
        autoplay: true,
      })}
  ,[touched]);

  function usernameChangeHandler(e){
    setUserId(e.target.value);
  }

  function passwordChangeHandler(e){
    touched ? setTouched(true) : setTouched(false);
    setPassword(e.target.value);
  }

  function formSubmitHandler(e){
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  return (
    <div id='wrapper'>
      <div id='avatar' style={{ width: 300, height: 300 }}></div>
      <form onSubmit={(e) => formSubmitHandler()}>
        <label id='login-bar'>
          <input 
            id='user-name'
            placeholder='Username'
            value = {userId}
            onChange = {(e) => usernameChangeHandler(e)}
            onFocus={() => setTouched(true)}
            onBlur={() => setTouched(false)}
          />
          <input
            id='password'
            placeholder='Password'
            type='password'
            value = {password}
            onChange = {(e) => passwordChangeHandler(e)}
            onFocus={() => setTouched(true)}
            onBlur={() => setTouched(false)}
          />
        </label>
        <button id='submit-btn' type='Submit'>Login</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

On running this code, the page renders a new animation each time I click the username or password input, while all the previous ones are still present. I want it to only show one animation based on what the user is doing. How do I make that change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each time the `lottie.loadAnimation` is launched, it creates a new animation element in the container (your case `document.getElementById('avatar')`).

To prevent that, you first want to unload, or destroy, the current animation before appending a new one. This can simply be done by adding `lottie.destroy()` at the start of your useEffect like so:

```
 useEffect(() => {
      lottie.destroy();
      lottie.loadAnimation({
        container: document.getElementById('avatar'),
        animationData: touched ? nod : sideNod,
        renderer: 'svg',
        loop: true,
        autoplay: true,
      })}
,[touched]);
```

This will destroy ALL animations. To prevent that, you can set a name for your animation and specify it in the destroy method like so:

```
 useEffect(() => {
      lottie.destroy('login_animation');
      lottie.loadAnimation({
        name: 'login_animation',
        container: document.getElementById('avatar'),
        animationData: touched ? nod : sideNod,
        renderer: 'svg',
        loop: true,
        autoplay: true,
      })}
,[touched]);
```

Also, since you are using React, would recommend switching to a react package for animations rather than using the web version: https://www.npmjs.com/package/lottie-react. Up to you.